# c++ Can I save changes in memory in an running program permanently?

Tags: c++, memory, executable, self-modifying

I modified the memory of an executable while its running, but can I save the changes inside the compiled executable permanently so I still have the changes of the memory after restarting it?

I saw something similar on OllyDbg that can save modified memory  into a new executable, but I don't want to create a extra file.

Is there a way?

Comment: you probably want something like [CheatEngine](http://www.cheatengine.org/)..

Comment: GNU Emacs used to do something like this (not sure if they still do); it was called `undump`.  The idea was that they would load and compile all the Lisp code into memory, then dump everything back to the executable so the compilation wouldn't have to be redone every time the editor started. It was a pretty horrible hack, as I recall, and not something I would suggest unless you have an extremely good reason.

Comment: Thank you Nate Eldredge!